# How can I develop a shell script for AIX if I don't have an AIX appliance?

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

I have a `ksh93` based script for AIX systems I want to enhance. Is there any known way to "test" (in terms of trial and error) such a script without having to make a physical AIX system my own?

Nice would be something like [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) for shells on various systems..

How would you do it?

Comment: you could try - https://tio.run/#ksh, which has `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`

Comment: Well, `ksh` in itself might be perfectly compatible; the other programs you start from your script could still cause problems: the GNU versions of the common utilities (find, sed, grep etc) has much more features than their AIX counterparts.

Comment: Apparently you cannot: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10408/4667, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3963923/7552

Comment: Polarhome offers shell accounts for many OSes, including an AIX 7.1 box.